# How many users can be added to MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql

The question is simple. I would like to know that is there any limit on number of users that can be added to a MySQL Server.

Comment: What an odd question.

Comment: Hmm...After knowing the answer, I thought in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit per se. It is limited only by the disk space you have to store the mysql.user table.